# oracle golden gate with IBM DB2 for i

Tags: db2, oracle-golden-gate

I am new to oracle golden gate. The requirement is to extract the changed data from IBM DB2 for i-Series (source database).Is it possible to run Oracle GoldenGate for IBM DB2 for i

i) in a remote system to extract the data from the source database?

ii) Oracle Golden Gate for IBM DB2 for i can be run as container inside a x86 platform?

I have read inside oracle document that “Oracle Golden Gate for DB2 for i runs directly on a DB2 for i source system to capture data from the transaction journals for replication to a target system”.is that means it is only possible to run ogg4db2 for i in the same system where db2 database(source) is running? and no option to run it in a remote m/c which can connect to the source db and extract the data?